# With .NET Maui, what am I missing in this simple command-navigation scenario?

Tags: routes, data-binding, command, maui

Another newbie question, trying to implement navigation using RelayCommand and Navigation classes. I have a fairly simple setup with .NET Maui using MVVM. I have two views with corresponding ViewModels. I have setup a navigation that should get me from the main view to the edit view and back again. Put a single button on the main view to navigate to the edit view, and a single button on the edit view to navigate back. No joy. It compiles and runs, but it won't even navigate to the edit view... it simply does nothing when I click the button. I think I messed something up in the command binding to the button, or it could be that the navigation isn't bound properly.

I will post the code that should navigate me from MainPlayerPage to EditPage... since that isn't working, the rest of it can wait.

EDIT: I think the issue is in the command binding. I've tried substituting a different command to make it change the text on the second label, and it doesn't seem to work for that, either.

I have a MainPlayerPage whose xaml looks like this:

*EDIT: I added a second button with a different command, this one to change the second label text. This command doesn't work, either, so I'm thinking I'm doing the command bindings wrong?*

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MySolution.Mobile.MainPlayerPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             Title="MainPlayerPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to Main Player Page!"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="24"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Navigate To Edit Page"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="36"
                Margin="5,20,5,5"
                Command="{Binding NavigateToEditPageCommand}">
        </Button>
        <Button Text="Change Text on Second Label"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="36"
                Margin="5,20,5,5"
                Command="{Binding ChangeSecondLabelTextCommand, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </Button>
        <Label
            Text="{Binding Identifier, StringFormat='From ViewModel: {0}'}"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="18"
            Margin="0,15,0,0">
        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The code-behind in MainPlayerPage.xaml.cs is simple and looks like:

```
public partial class MainPlayerPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPlayerPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainPlayerViewModel(new NavigationService());
    }
}
```

The label after the button is just to confirm that the BindingContext is set correctly to pull from the ViewModel, and it must be because the label displays the hard-coded value of the Identifier property in the ViewModel. The corresponding ViewModel:

*EDIT: I added a second command to change the text on the label. It doesn't work, either.*

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MySolution.Client.Core.Navigation;

namespace MySolution.Client.Core.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainPlayerViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private String _identifier = "Just to make sure the BindingContext is set properly...";

        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

        public IAsyncRelayCommand NavigateToEditPageCommand;
        public AsyncRelayCommand ChangeSecondLabelTextCommand;

        public MainPlayerViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
            NavigateToEditPageCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(NavigateToEditPage);
            ChangeSecondLabelTextCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(ChangeSecondLabelText);
        }

        private Task NavigateToEditPage()
            => navigationService.GoToEdit();

        private Task ChangeSecondLabelText()
        {
            Identifier = "And now we change the text of the second label...";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

The Navigation Service looks like this:

```
namespace MySolution.Client.Core.Navigation
{
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        Task GoToEdit();
        Task GoBack();
    }
}
```

```
namespace MySolution.Mobile.Navigation
{
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        private async Task Navigate(String pageName)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(pageName);
        }

        public Task GoToEdit() => Navigate("EditPage");

        public Task GoBack() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

And in the AppShell.xaml.cs, I register the routes as follows:

```
    public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPlayerPage", typeof(MainPlayerPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("EditPage", typeof(EditPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("AboutPage", typeof(AboutPage));
        }
    }
```

Finally, the App.xaml.cs looks like this:

EDIT: I changed this in accordance with Liyun Zhang's answer, and it made no difference.

```
namespace LifeTrax.Mobile
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }
}
```

If there is anything else I need to post, I can do so in an edit. I THINK the problem is in the command binding or the navigation setup, but if it is I don't know what I did wrong. Something simple, probably. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPlayerPage());` in the App.cs, so you didn't use the AppShell and can't use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(pageName)` to navigate in the `NavigationPage`.

You can set the MainPage as AppShell( `MainPage = new AppShell();`) in the App.cs and then please use the [RelayCommand attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand#how-it-works) instead of the `IAsyncRelayCommand`. Such as:

```
namespace MySolution.Client.Core.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainPlayerViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private String _identifier = "Just to make sure the BindingContext is set properly...";

        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

        public MainPlayerViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;      
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        private Task NavigateToEditPage()
            => navigationService.GoToEdit();

        [RelayCommand]
        private Task ChangeSecondLabelText()
        {
            Identifier = "And now we change the text of the second label...";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've continued to tinker trying to get it to work since I posted this, and that's actually one I've tried. I changed my app.xaml.cs to look like this, and it still doesn't navigate. To be honest, I'm more and more thinking it is the command binding and the navigation isn't even firing.

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }

Comment: Please check the update answer and I have tested it. The navigation worked. @MatthewGivens

Comment: Bingo zap! So it was the command binding, though I was also confused on the navigation. You know, for an old Windows Forms programmer, this stuff is... interesting.

Thanks!